# Creating odds calculator, having trouble with math.random

Tags: math, lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to print odds for 40% against 60%. I found that math.random() function doesn't do decimal numbers, anyone know a way around this?

Please see my code and my comment on the math.random.

```
while (nFlip <= 99) do
    randomFlip = math.random (0,2.5) -- Trying to get 40% by doing 0-2.5
      nFlip = nFlip + b 
      print( randomFlip )
    if randomFlip == 2.5 then
        countHeads = countHeads + b
    end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use inequality instead of equality.

```
if math.random(0,4) < 2 then
    -- this will run 40% of the time
end
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I'm not as math incline as you are, can you give me the math.random() for 60%? while i study your formula.

Comment: `math.random` has even chances of generating each number in its range (in this case, `0,1,2,3,4`). Since there are 5 numbers, each has a 100/5 = 20% chance. To make it 60%, you'd just increase the number to the right of the inequality by one to add another 20%, e.g. `< 3`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the code is clearer if you use:

```
if math.random() < 0.4 then
    -- this will run 40% of the time
end
```

because this returns a floating point value between 0 and 1 so the comparison has a clear relationship to the percentage.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want math.random() to give you values from 0 to 2.5, try:
`math.random() * 10 % 2.5`.

Also, assuming you want different results each time you run the program; don't forget to use:
`math.randomseed(os.time())`